# validate inputs than close the div once filled out

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am really new to HTML,JavaScript and was just wondering how I would check to see if the input fields inside my `fieldset` were completed by the user, if so the `fieldset` collapses into its legend. Below I have created the script to collapse the `fieldset` into the legend, I just need to create the validation script but I don't know how to create it.

```js
function doit2() {
  if (document.getElementById('two').style.display == 'none') {
    document.getElementById('two').style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('two').style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend><a href="#" onclick="doit2()">Personal details</a></legend>
  <div id="two">
    <div>
      <label>Surname or family name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="personal" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Given name/names:</label>
      <input type="text" name="personal" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label> Date of birth:</label>
      <input type="date" name="personal" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label> Male </label>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label> Female </label>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label> N/A </label>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="NA" />
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
function validateForm()
{
  debugger;
  var fields = ["surname", "name", "dob"]
  var i, l = fields.length;
  var fieldname;
  for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    fieldname = fields[i];
    if (document.getElementsByName(fieldname)[0].value === "") {
      alert(fieldname + " can not be empty");
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
function doit2() {
    
    if(document.getElementById('two').style.display == 'none'){
        document.getElementById('two').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        
        if(validateForm()){
        document.getElementById('two').style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<fieldset id="fieldset">
    <legend><a href="#" onclick="doit2()">Personal details</a></legend>
    <div id="two">
        <div>
            <label>Surname or family name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="surname"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Given name/names:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label> Date of birth:</label>
            <input type="date" name="dob"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label> Male </label>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" checked/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label> Female </label>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label> N/A </label> 
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="NA"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: I've got a feeling the fieldset won't close because of the radio buttons?

Comment: The field-set will closed after you filled all text box fields and its working for me

Comment: Is there a way to make the fieldset automatically close once the user has filled out everything?

Answer (score 0):

The first step in validation you need to add to each input `required` inside input tag. Than if you fine with default validation you can leave it as is, other wise you can use regex. If yu decide to use any of the frameworks - bootstrap, angular - they have their own validators as well

Comment: yes, the validation is not browser specific, you can check caniuse website always. of course very old browsers will not support it, but they will not support html5 either

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`document.getElementById("[id of element]").value`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp) or [`document.getElementsByName("[Name of element]").value`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp) to get value of your inputs and validate them.for your case you can use `document.getElementsByName` Like this:

```js
function validate() {
  if (document.getElementsByName('personal')[0].value.length == 0) {
    //set error
    alert('error');
    return false;
  }
  //Add other validation here
  return true;
}
//....
function doit2() {
  if (validate()) {
    if (document.getElementById('two').style.display == 'none') {
      document.getElementById('two').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      document.getElementById('two').style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend><a href="#" onclick="doit2()">Personal details</a></legend>
  <div id="two">
    <div>
      <label>Surname or family name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="personal" />
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: but how do I first check if all inputs are filled, than run my small script? could you give me a basic example for a single input? Thanks for all the help!